# Kivymd not able to keep label and textfield in same row

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have created a form with kivymd label and textfield but somehow the labels and the textfields are not in proper alignment with each other. The mdlabel is aligning a little above the row of mdtextfield with pos_hint function. My codes are below:

```
#.py

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import *

class Main(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

MyApp().run()

#.kv
#:import Vector kivy.vector.Vector
<Main>:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "challan"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "My App"
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
             
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Date'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id:date
                        hint_text: "Date"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width: 300

                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Challan No.'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id: challan
                        hint_text: "Challan No."
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}          
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width:300

                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Quantity'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id:qty
                        hint_text: "Quantity"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width: 300

                    MDLabel:
                        text:'From Location'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id: flo
                        hint_text: "From Location"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width:300
                    
            Screen:
                name: "Message"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "My App"
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                    MDLabel:
                        text:"Email: "
                        # font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**4
                        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
                        size_hint: 0.25, 0.15

                    MDTextField:
                        id:namee
                        hint_text: "Name"
                        helper_text:"forget"
                        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.0 ,'center_y':0.0}
                        size_hint_x : None
                        width: 300

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id:nav_drawer
            opening_transition:'out_bounce'
            opening_time:1
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                    icon: "android"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: 'Android'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "challan"
                MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                    icon: "magnify"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    text: 'Search'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "Message"
                Widget:
```

I want to keep the label and the text field in same row in alignment to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The `MDBoxLayout` design intent is to place each child in a separate row when `orientation` is `vertical`. If you want items aligned horizontally, you can use `MDBoxLayout` with `orientation` of `horizontal` (which is the default).

In your case, one way to accomplish your goal is to put the pairs of `MDLabel` and `MDTextInput` each in their own `horizontal` `MDBoxLayout`. For example:

```
        Screen:
            name: "challan"
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: "My App"
                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
         
                MDBoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Date'
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id:date
                        hint_text: "Date"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width: 300
                        
                MDBoxLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Challan No.'
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                        theme_text_color:'Primary'

                    MDTextField:
                        id: challan
                        hint_text: "Challan No."
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}     
                        size_hint:(None,None)
                        width:300
```

Similarly, for the rest of the items that you want on their own row.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  With this my toolbar is at the bottom of my screen. I don't understand how `pos_hint` works wih `kivymd`

Comment: Is `MDToolbar` still the first item after the first `MDBoxLayout` in your `kv`?